# Identify stack and heap segments in macOS current process

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, heap-memory

I'd like to add memory profiler to my daemon which runs under macOS. In linux, i could simply check the `/proc/<pid>/map` for any mapped memory in the process, and look for pathname = [heap] or pathname = [stack].

Is there any alternative mac syscall/MIG/mach message for that purpose ?

I've tried to see if `proc_pidinfo` contain any valuable information, but unfortunately nothing related to my needs.

Notice that apple provide such tool for other remote processes called `vmmap` and it doesn't provide any api at all (it's merely command-line tool) and there's no public API for this demand, but perhaps there's an API to extract this information from "within" the process itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what public APIs (if any) it uses, but the closest equivalent to Linux's `/proc/$pid/maps` in macOS is the `vmmap` utility. Running it with a PID as an argument will give you a detailed report on all regions mapped by the process, including some interesting details on memory usage within `malloc` zones.

Comment: Yes it does, but i'd like to base an in-process memory profiler so i need some API, are you familiar with any private one ? thanks

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337740/is-there-any-api-for-the-command-vmmap) may help.